# Better password recovery extension?

Tags: extensions, magento-1.4

If a user forgets her password, she can request a new one which will be sent as plain text by mail. Is there a way (extension for example) to not send the password directly, but a password recovery link which is only valid for a certain amount of time?

Thanks!

Comment: What version are you using? This is a default behavior on the latest versions

Comment: I am using 1.4 which does not support that feature I think.

Comment: I think you should upgrade. To 1.8 at least. And it will solve your problem...and many more.

Comment: Yeah, but I cant :), I have to solve it with the version I currently have.

Comment: Then get the 1.8 or 1.9 version, and see if you can extract the password recovery system from there.

Answer (score 2):

You have a ton of bugs and security issues with your version. There is "no alternative" to upgrade! This said, check out the code of Magento 1.9 for the sendPasswordForgottenEmail.

It starts here:

```
\Mage_Customer_AccountController::forgotPasswordPostAction
```

generates a password reset token:

```
$newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
$customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
```

sends an email with this token `app/locale/en_US/template/email/account_password_reset_confirmation.html`

If you click on it, the token is checked `\Mage_Customer_AccountController::resetPasswordAction`, then you can reset your password: `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php:591`